# Swift Eureka: Update Eureka tableView's style

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

Is there a way to update Eureka's tableView style so that it shows a `grouped` or `insetGrouped` style instead of `plain` style?

I attempted `tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .insetGrouped)` in viewDidLoad but the Form is still showing `plain` style.

Answer (score 2):

It's easier than I expected: in your FormViewController's init, call super.init with the style you need.

```
init() {
    super.init(style: .insetGrouped)
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks so much for the solution. Your solution kinda work, but if you add PushRows to the form, the pushed viewController is still the plain style. Any clue how do we cascade the style to the pushed viewController? The solution should ideally apply throughout the form.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to overriding it in init(), which force you to override another init function,  you can also put it in the ViewDidLoad(), note that you need to put it before the call to super, as there's where the tableViewStyle is being used.

```
public override func viewDidLoad() {
    tableViewStyle = .insetGrouped
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

I have my own function that overrides FormViewController with some of these defaults, and all my EurekaForms extends from them. For example:

```
public class MyFormViewController: FormViewController {
    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        tableViewStyle = .insetGrouped
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

All your form then can extend from this to get it insetGrouped style.